# Embedding power BI report into web app – Error acquiring token

Tags: c#, powerbi, access-token

Embedding power BI report into web app – Error acquiring token

I have a .NET framework Web Application which uses Azure AD to authenticate the users. This is within an app registration which is of type 'Web app/API'

Within the web app I am trying to embed a power BI report from a master account (which has MFA enabled) so that users can see the report without having to login.

I am having trouble when trying to acquire a token using this code:

```
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);

                //// Authenticate using created credentials
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
                var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, credential);
```

I am getting this exception message:
Message = "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access

The IT admin will not remove MFA from the master account.

Is there another method I can use to embed the report into my web app without the user having to login and without removing the MFA from the master account? Or a way around the MFA issue?
Note: I have granted access to ‘Azure AD’ and ‘Power BI Api’ within the app registration.
Note: I have tried creating a new app registration of type 'native' and still get the same error.